Multi-Threaded Code only runs sequentially
I've written a simple Class that will execute upto N blocking tasks (N specified during initialization) concurrently using unique_lock & condition_variable.
My code compiles and runs but only sequentially. What am I doing wrong here?
class Work_Queue {

    mutex lock;
    condition_variable cv;
    int thrd_ctr, max_thrd;
    queue<pair<int, int>> wq;
    map<int, int> am;

public:
    Work_Queue(int cap) {
        max_thrd = cap;
        thrd_ctr = 0;
    }

    void churn() {
        if (!wq.empty()) {
            unique_lock<mutex> ul(lock);
            cv.wait(ul, [this]() { return (thrd_ctr < max_thrd); });
            auto [ip, id] = wq.front();
            wq.pop();
            ++thrd_ctr;
            cout << "thrd # " << thrd_ctr << " started" << endl;
            ip++;
            sleep(1);
            cout << "thrd # " << thrd_ctr << " ended" << endl;
            am[id] = ip;
            --thrd_ctr;
            cv.notify_all();
        }
    }

    void do_work(int ip, int id) {
        wq.push({ ip, id });
        thread thrdobj([&]() { churn(); });
        thrdobj.detach();
    }

    int get_ans(int id) {
        while (am.find(id) == am.end()) {
            // do nothing
        }
        return am[id];
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << "Number of cores: " << thread::hardware_concurrency() << endl;
    Work_Queue q(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        q.do_work(i, i + 5);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        cout << q.get_ans(i + 5) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

The output I get is
Number of cores: 8
thrd # 1 started
thrd # 1 ended
1
thrd # 1 started
thrd # 1 ended
2
thrd # 1 started
thrd # 1 ended
3..

What's causing it to still run sequentially and how can I fix it?
I checked to see if the number of cores was limited to 1 preventing concurrency, but thread::hardware_concurrency()  is showing me multiple cores.
I was expecting the number in thrd # 1 started to go as high as 4.

You actually did write a thread that will handle items in a queue sequentially. So the code is doing exactly what you told it to do. Somewhere your code should create more then one thread, And you would need to have your queue function to have a cv.notify_one to wake up one of those threads.

Two things: You're sleeping with a lock held. You have a race accessing wq from multiple threads without locks. Generally, document clearly which lock protects which data. This helps you make up your mind and avoid mistakes.

Unless I'm mistaken do_work and churn both access wp without any synchronization: that's undefined behaviour.

An your churn is holding on to the mutex for the entire duration of its runtime... basically, the way you should handle queues like this, is to remove the item that you want to work on so it's now owned by your thread, and release the lock so another thread can  fetch another item.

A side note: calling detach on a thread [almost] always indicates a bad design. And good practice dictates joining all created threads.


My code...runs but only sequentially
The output I get is...

I think you are asking why the thrd_ctr always is 1 when your code prints it. Am I right? If so, then the answer is simple. Christian Stieber said it in a comment, but I'll spell it out in more detail.
Your churn function includes these lines:
{
    unique_lock<mutex> ul(lock);
    ...
    ++thrd_ctr;
    cout << "thrd # " << thrd_ctr << " started" << endl;
    ...
    cout << "thrd # " << thrd_ctr << " ended" << endl;
    ...
    --thrd_ctr;
    ...
}

The lock is locked when any thread hits the thrd_ctr++ statement, and it stays locked until after the thread executes thrd_ctr--. The lock ensures that no two threads can ever be in that same block of code at the same time. So, the value of thrd_ctr is guaranteed not to be changed by any other thread. And, it's guaranteed that whenever the thread exits from the block, the value of thrd_ctr will be set back to the same value (zero) that it had when the thread entered the block.
Every thread increments thrd_ctr from zero to one, prints it twice, and decrements it back to zero before any other thread is allowed to execute those same lines.

P.S., As other commenters have pointed out, this is not the only mistake in your example.
